# Why does Chrome hang when I request a specific URL?

Tags: google-chrome

For one particular page on a site I'm working on, Chrome hangs on sending the request for the page. I've checked the Apache access and error logs on my server, and the request is simply not sent. Here is what I see in the Chrome network console:

[image]

Chrome will sit with the request pending like this for minutes, and will not ever actually load the page.

If I alter the URL that I request by adding some garbage GET parameters (e.g. changing `https://mysite/index.php?page=results_bundles` to `https://mysite/index.php?page=results_bundles&foobar` the page loads fine. If I make the same request in an incognito window the page loads fine, and if I make it from a different browser it loads fine.

I've tried clearing my cache to no avail. What could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After disabling all of my extensions and clearing the cookies for the domain, I still had no results. I ended up closing and re-opening chrome, re-enabling all my extensions, and now it works fine. Not sure what the actual problem was, but that solved it.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, and quitting + restarting Chrome fixed it for me as well. A specific URL wasn't working in Chrome. Any variation (adding a query parameter, changing the capitalization of the page name, etc.) avoided the problem. Loading the same page in Safari worked. After quitting + restarting Chrome, everything was fine. I didn't have to mess around with extensions or cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your cookies for this domain.

According to your explanation this is the only difference between incognito and non-incognito.

Also your extensions might cause this issue.

Check if the access logs for Apache are set up correctly.